# Regarding proving a set to be a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

To prove a set to be a vector space, is the existence of an additive inverse independent of the existence of an additive identity or zero element?

Comment: They are dependent. How do you even define an inverse if you don't have the neutral?

Comment: Well, the book that we have been assigned to do says that it can happen. There is a question in it in which it is asked whether a set of all solutions of the linear non homogeneous differential equation y"-3y'+2y=x is a vector space or not.If it isn't, then specify which properties it doesn't follow.What should be the answer? According to me, it is not closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication and doesn't have a zero element and additive inverse.But the answer in the book doesn't mention anything about additive inverse.

Comment: @user8734617 What should be the answer?

Comment: I'd side with the book in this case. If there is no neutral, the very notion of "inverse" is meaningless, you cannot even check it.